# Alias column value use with limit clause mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

I have one table of clockin , in this table i have 600 records. I want to keep the first 250 records and delete the rest of the records.

I want to keep offset value dynamic from mysql query.

1. DELETE FROM `clockin` order by id asc limit 250,1000;

[image: fetched error]

2. DELETE FROM `clockin` order by id asc limit 263,(SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM `clockin`)-250);

[image: error]

Does anyone help me.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html - 'The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants, with these exceptions:

Within prepared statements, LIMIT parameters can be specified using ? placeholder markers.

Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.' - etc

Comment: You can't use an OFFSET in Mysql and LIMIT in the DELETE clause and even LIMIT has its limits only `DELETE FROM clockin WHERE 1= 1 order by id asc limit 250;` is vlaid

Comment: Note the lack of offset option here - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html

Comment: SET @limit:=(SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM clockin)-250); SET @s = CONCAT('delete FROM clockin order by id desc LIMIT ',@limit); PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s; EXECUTE stmt1; it's working , thank you:)